# How to set SSL versions in script when there are multiple URLs in a concurrent group of requests in a Single script?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen, hp-performance-center

There are 2 different URLs in a script that I have recorded and each use a different version of SSL. There is a concurrent group inside the script which has requests with both the URLs. How do I set the SSL version for them without removing the concurrency part?

I have tried using WinInet mode for replay which solved the issue. But I need to measure the response time for each URL and I cannot achieve it using WinInet mode as it doesn't generate the Web Page Diagnostics graph.

I've also tried creating automatic transactions but I couldn't see any of them in the results summary.

Comment: Can you please put the SSL version outside the concurrent group?

Comment: Of course that can be put. But the question here is again the same. How to provide 2 different versions, if the same concurrent group has 2 different URLs using 2 different SSL Versions?

Comment: You can use & in the ssl option function. e.g. 2&3. The SSL version preference: '2', '3', '2&3', 'TLS', 'TLS1.1', or 'TLS1.2'

Comment: I executed below code. It works for me.

web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION","2&3"); 
//your request
web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION","TLS1.2");
//your another request
`

Comment: This works. But it throws an error if it is in the below format web_concurrent_start().... web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION","2&3"); //your request web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION","TLS1.2");... web_concurrent_end();

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Function cannot be used inside a concurrent group

Comment: That's correct. Concurrent group has restrictions. You cannot use all the functions within a concurrent group.

Comment: That is what the problem was as pointed out.

Comment: It is not a problem. It is how LoadRunner works :)

Comment: I didn't say it was a problem with load runner. But the problem is with the way I want to execute. I'd asked if there was any way to make things work this way.

Comment: You cannot violate the design. PS. In LoadRunner 12.60, SSL2 is no longer supported. Please watch this video for more details. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd_v-QWLOnQ

Comment: I do not want to violate the design. But I want to know if there is any work around for this. As you see, the application uses 2 different URLs, of which one uses SSL 3 and the other one is on TLS1.2. So, I have a problem placing them both in a single concurrent group.

Comment: You cannot do that at this moment. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the servers involved, then enable the time-taken HTTP log field.  If you are running IIS, which is a good chance with WinInet, then the default log model for IIS will give you what you need.

At the conclusion of your tests, pull the logs.  Use Microsoft logparser (staying with the Microsoft theme), to pull the min, max, avg time-taken values, grouped by request and filtered on the IP addresses of your load generators.

Comment: I currently do not have the access to the servers. But the respective teams are saying that the times recorded in the servers are not abnormal. So, need to know for sure from the LG point of view.

Comment: Then for the one call you are interested in use strict URL mode with concurrent groups.   Probably the easiest way to do this is to ensure that the label tags for automatic transactions are correct and then run a single user in a single group from the load generator where you are interested with the URL mode with concurrent group requests and time each request.

Answer (score 0):

it would be interesting to know which SSL versions you have.

the following function let you set the SSL version before the URL call:

web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "put your tls version here");

accepted are TLS1, TLS1.1, TLS1.2 and more. 
See the Help hitting F1 on the function to get more information.

Comment: The versions are TLS1.2 and SSL 2&3. The problem here is, I cannot call the function as these requests will be in a concurrent group.